# a factor in the numerator is the opposite of the denominator - simplifies to -1

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm working on a little khan academy problem, finding the limit as `x -> 36` in the solution the program explains in the last step that since there are opposite factors in the numerator and denominator, they reduce to `-1`

`(36−x)(x√+6)/x−36` = `(-1)(x√+6)`

I've not encountered this situation before and I'm having a terrible time of finding resources to explain this contingency.

It's also possible that I'm just reading the problem incorrectly.

Is this in fact what is taking place? I suppose I understand the logic behind it, I'm very inexperienced so any reinforcement of this concept would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with `x√+6`? Do you mean $x\sqrt{6}$, $x+\sqrt{6}$ or $\sqrt{x}+6$

Comment: @Darksonn my mistake, its meant to be sqrt(x) - sorry I need to read up on formatting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The reason you result in a $-1$ is because you can factor out a $-1$ from the numerator. Let $a$ be any number.
$$\frac{a-x}{x-a} = \frac{(-1)(x-a)}{x-a} = -1.$$

Tricks like these are common in solving limit problems with discontinuities.